# Unable to open portable projects in vs2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, portable-class-library, incompatibility

I have a several (c#) solutions (originally created with VS2012) that include portable libraries that I have trouble opening with VS2013. Some of them fail to open with

> Unsupported This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the
>   following projects. The project types may not be installed or this
>   version of Visual Studio may not support them.

The problem only happens on my home environment. At work or on other setups everything works as expected.

To get it to work on my home environment, I have to right-click on the projects and choose "Edit Project.csproj ..." from the context menu for any project that was not loaded correctly. If all projects are open as text files in VS, I close the solution and reopen it again. Now, the projects failed to open, since VS is unable to open a project in two different modes (as a project vs as a text file). If you choose now "reload" from the context menu, the project loads correctly.
I can now close the solutions, and if I am lucky, eveything works after I reopen it again.

After some time, some of the projects fail to load. Then, I try to do the edit/reload trick again, but when I reload the solution, other portable projects are doomed. So, I have no choice but to start over (deleting the `suo` file takes me back to square-one, all portable projects are unable to load).

Any idea what I have screwed up with my system? I have installed all service packs and extensions. I also have the newest resharper version installed.

**Update:**
Not sure if it is related but I just got the following compiler warning for one of the incompatible projects

```
Warning 1   The element 'PropertyGroup' in namespace
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' has invalid child element  
'MinimumVisualStudioVersion' in namespace 
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'. List of possible elements 
expected: 'Property, ....   Project.csproj  1
```

**Update 2:**
VS Output window shows `The application for the project is not installed.` for all those projects that cannot be loaded. "Repairing" VS did not help, I will try to do a clean reinstall now.

Comment: Do you use any kind of source control? Are any other people editing/saving the projects at any point in this process?

Comment: We use gitm bit nobody else is doing any editing/saving.